# Advice on Group Function

Tags: sorting, excel-formula, header, digital-signature, muenchian-grouping

I have a data which requires stakeholders to sign off (probably mention a comment) in multiple columns. Can I use an automation function where there is a header row created for these data sets and instead of signing off in 10 columns they can just do 1 header.

(The header should work basis the data in column B, hence we should have 3 headers and people should be sign off in 1 header instead 2 columns)

Example Sheet :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 123 |
| Apple | 123 |
| Orange | 456 |
| Orange | 456 |
| Grapes | 789 |
| Grapes | 789 |

I tried grouping option but it requires manual function every time I add data. I am looking to have an automate function where basis the data in column B, grouping and header is created.

Comment: You need to provide an example of what the result would look like (and would the header data come from column A?)

Comment: Hi, the outcome I expect is
Apple 123
Orange 456
Grapes 789
with the duplicate values not deleted but just collapsed.

Comment: What's with the `Cell 3` then?

Comment: Should be an error, please read that as Grapes instead.

Comment: On Office 365: `=Unique(A1:B6)`